# What does it mean to "solve forward/backward" a differential equation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, economics

I know what it means to solve forward/backward difference equations. What I have not been able to wrap my head around is how that formally makes sense in continuous time. To make things concrete, here is an example from an economics paper I have been reading. Take the following differential equation (which describes the evolution of debt $b_t$, I will skip the economics specifics)

$$
db_t = s_t dt + r_t b_t dt
$$
Note that the $t$ subscripts denotes the state of the variable at time $t$. In the paper, the author then "solves forward" this equation to get

$$
b_0 = \lim_{T \to \infty} \left[- \int_0^T e^{-\bar{r}_t t}s_tdt + e^{-\bar{r}_T T} b_T\right],
$$
where $\bar{r}_t = (1/t) \int_0^t r_s ds$. Now, here is my proposed solution. We can write the differential equation (using an integrating factor) as

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-\bar{r}_t t} b_t \right) = e^{-\bar{r}_t t}s_t
$$

Integrating from $0$ to $T$,  we get

\begin{align}
\int_0^T \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-\bar{r}_t t} b_t \right) dt &= \int_0^T e^{-\bar{r}_t t}s_tdt\\
e^{-\bar{r}_T T} b_T - b_0 &= \int_0^T e^{-\bar{r}_t t}s_tdt,
\end{align}
which, when taking the limit gives us the equation.

So here's my question finally. To me, it seems I just "solved" a differential equation. Where was the "forward" part of my solution, if it is there at all? How would the "backward" solution look, and which part would I need to change?

As is probably clear, I am not well versed in differential equations. So, if possible, try to keep it simple. Thank you!

Comment: In short, solving forward means to use $f(t)$ to get $f(t+h)$, and backward goes the other way - use $f(t+h)$ to get $f(t)$. This is common in numerical methods.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks, this is equivalent to the difference equation case. However, you're not really addressing the question.

Comment: The solution process is forward, from a, possibly unknown, state $b_0$ to $b_T$. This is a standard process of finding an integrating factor, or in other terms, finding the homogeneous solution and then applying variation-of-constants. Then this solution is used to derive information backwards, to derive the state $b_0$ from future discounted account movements, possibly assuming some kind of balancing so that the second term converges to zero.